# Oauth2 flow for mixed server/client app

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, oauth, passport.js

I'm trying to work out the best flow for accessing Oauth2 api's in my application.

The server will be built in Nodejs (using PassportJs??) and should store the basic user profile details for each external service the user has given permission to use (Facebook, Twitter, etc..) Within a single user object in my app.
For example: User1 might have granted access to show photos from their FB or Google+ accounts.

The client will be written in HTML/Js and will be accessed via the server, but may also be included in hybrid mobile app that would need to be able to run in an offline mode too.

I would like to keep the basic user profile information on server but access the authorised APIs directly from the client without proxying everything through my server.
I.e. the client could ask for /graph.Facebook.com/blah rather than /myapp.com/Facebook/blah

I'm struggling to work out how I should set up the with in this scenario as I have no experience using Oauth providers.

Can anyone suggest how this can be done?